# I want to store my primarykey values into foreignkey field

Tags: django

This is my models

class Tasklist(models.Model):

```
clientname= models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
task = models.CharField(max_length=100)
startdate = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)
enddate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
assignee = models.CharField(max_length=30)
status = models.CharField(max_length=30)
fstatus = models.BooleanField(default=False)


def __str__(self):
    return self.task + " - Task - " + str(self.fstatus)
```

class edit_page(models.Model):

```
old_id = models.ForeignKey(Tasklist,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
updatedate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
time_from = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
time_to = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
messagelogs = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.messagelogs
```

This is My Views page

def edit_task(request, task_id):
if request.method == "POST":

```
        updatedate=request.POST.get("updatedate","")
        time_from=request.POST.get("time_from","")
        time_to=request.POST.get("time_to","")
        messagelogs=request.POST.get("messagelogs","")
        test_list=edit_page(updatedate=updatedate,time_from=time_from,time_to=time_to,messagelogs=messagelogs)
        test_list.save()
       

        task = Tasklist.objects.get(pk=task_id)
        form = TaskForm(request.POST or None, instance = task)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()  
                    
        messages.success(request,("Task Edited "))
        return redirect('email_updatetask', (task_id))
        return  redirect('todolist')

else:
      task_obj = Tasklist.objects.get(pk=task_id)
      return render(request, 'edit.html', {'task_obj': task_obj})
```

**can u pls how can i store my primary keys into the second foreign key field via HTML files....**

Comment: Sorryy can u pls how can i store my primary key values into the  foreign key field via HTML files....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have two tables.